# iOS speech to text service stops listening after 20 sec

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

When running IBM Speech to Text iOS sample code, after around 20 seconds, speech to text stops with following message: stopRecordingAudio stopRecordingAudio->fclose done received --> { "state": "listening" } So how to fix this error? the code link is https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-ios-sdk.

Comment: please open an issue in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget: in this way you'll involve IBM Watson support team in checking and fix this issue. They will be able to perform in-depth investigation of your error.